# Unable to access session variable on cookie less PHP sessions

Tags: php, firefox, cookies, session-state

I am trying to use PHP session without using cookies. I have enabled session.use_trans_sid and disabled session.use_cookies in my php.ini file. I have also disabled cookies in my firefox browser. Now, when I navigate between pages, I am unable to access the variable in the session object set from a previous page. BTW, I am aware that using session IDs as part of the URL is not a recommended approach.

I have provided the sample code snippet below for the two pages - page1.php and page2.php. Page1.php sets a variable in the session object to true and page2.php checks this variable's value and takes action accordingly.

**Page1.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_REQUEST["user"]))
{
    $_SESSION["name"] = true;
    $host = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
    $path = dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
    header("Location: http://$host$path/page2.php");
    exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Page1</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get" action="/page1.php">
Name:<input type="text" name="user"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Login"/><br/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**page2.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION["name"])
{
    echo("<h1>Name set.</h1>");
}
else
{
     echo("<h1>Name NOT set.</h1>");
} 
?>
```

Comment: Can you show us some basic code you are using?

Comment: Is the session functionality working? Can we see the headers?

Comment: The reason you see the `GET /page1.php?PHPSESSID=v08...` is because of the `session_start` that gets fired when the form is first displayed. What is the header from the second request?

Comment: @George Edison: Here is the header after I enter a name and hit submit. "GET /page1.php?PHPSESSID=v08npgulpt044a75aqnbkrbq14&user=hello HTTP/1.1".

Comment: And it's not working? What does happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. Looks like php will not pass the session ID during re-directs as part of the re-direction URL even if the re-direct is to a page within the same website. This is why the session variable was not available within page2.php above and the output was always "Name NOT set". So I changed my re-direct URL on page1.php to have the session ID as part of it & that did the trick.

```
$sid = session_name() . "=" . session_id();
header("Location: http://$host$path/page2.php?$sid");
```

Comment: In trans_sid mode, PHP only inserts the session ID into HTML ('a' links and forms). It will not modify any javascript, onclick blocks, header() output, or externally linked files, such as CSS via 'link' headers.